# General solution to the Laplace equation in spherical coordinates

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

I'm currently going through Jackson chapters 3 and 4 and don't understand what exactly "$l$" or its physical meaning is when looking at the general solution to the Laplace equation in spherical coordinates, any clarification would be appreciated.

$$\sum_l (A_l r^l + B_l r^{-l-1}) P_l(\cos \theta).$$

Comment: Jackson might not be the place to *start* if you haven't seen multipole expansions yet. I know that's not very helpful, but Jackson is notoriously difficult, and it's probably worth going through another textbook first that has more explanations and such.  There are a lot of classics: Purcell, Griffiths, etc., that will explain what this expansion is.

Comment: Does the Wikipedia article on [Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) help? Do you know what a Taylor series is?

Comment: The wikipedia doesn't really help, I do know what a Taylor series is

Comment: The Wikipedia article [explains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Legendre_polynomials_in_multipole_expansions) that Legendre polynomials arise as a Taylor series. What about this is unclear?

Comment: Another approach: Did you take a QM course as an undergraduate and solve the 3D Schrodinger equation? The Legendre polynomials appeared as eigenfunctions and $l$ as an integer related to the eigenvalues. When you solve Laplace’s equation for EM, it’s similar. You separate variables and get a differential equation for the angular dependence of the potential. There is an infinite set of solutions, enumerated by $l$.

Comment: so essentially when im using the general solution to the Laplace equation each l that I plug in represents a different solution?

Comment: Each term is solution for any $l$. The constants $A_l$ and $B_l$ get determined by boundary conditions.